# AFNetworking success/failure blocks not invoked after the app goes in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, afnetworking

I am not able to get the success/failure blocks triggered if the request is started after the app goes in background. I can still see the request hitting the server successfully, but the callbacks are never triggered.

I was able to boil it down to this piece of code. It never logs success or failure.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    [manager GET:MY_API_PATH parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"SUCCESS!!");
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"FAILURE!!");

    }];
}
```

In case you're wondering why I need to do this, it's because, I need to have the app respond to a push notification when it's received in the background. I was seeing some inconsistent behavior there, so to make it simpler, I took out the APNS piece and started investigating AFNetworking's behavior in the background and ran into this.

Am I missing something? Appreciate any help!

Comment: We can show you how to have the app request a finite amount of time sufficient to receive and process the response from the above (see [Executing Finite Length Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3)), but this is a very different approach than responding to push notifications, so I'm not sure how useful this is for your broader question.

Comment: I see your point, Rob. For push notifications, I had implemented the `didReceiveRemoteNotification: fetchCompletionHandler:` delegate method and was able to capture the notification arrival event. From there, I was making an API call (just like above), and was not able to have the callbacks triggered about 80% of the times.

Comment: @Rob - So I followed the documentation, and the callbacks do get triggered now! If you want to post your comment as an answer (with any additional information about the APNS case, if you want), I'd be happy to accept it. In the meanwhile I'll try this in my APNS scenario and see if this technique would fix the inconsistency there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is explained here..
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: Thanks! Would appreciate if you could point to a specific section in that link.